# Which function should I use to replace variables in an expression?

Tags: output-formatting, replacement, symbolic

I tried to search around but could not find a good solution.

What I want to do is simple, for example, if at the beginning I define the three variables as:

```
vectora    = {ax, ay, az}
vectorb    = {bx, by, bz}
scalara    = Norm[vectora]
directiona = vectora/scalara
```

Then I do the operation:

```
Cross[vectorb, directiona]
```

Mathematica will displace it as

```
{(az by)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2] 
- (ay bz)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2],
-((az bx)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2])
+ (ax bz)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2], 
  (ay bx)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2]
- (ax by)/Sqrt[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2]}
```

I want it to be as concise as possible:

```
{(az by)/scalara - (ay bz)/scalara, -(ax bx)/scalara + (ax bz)/scalara, (ay bx)/scalara - (ax by)/scalara}
```

Which function should I use?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways I suppose one could do this. The problem is that you have already assign to `scalara` variable. So each time M sees `scalara` it will replace it by it value.

So if you want to assign `scalara` and still do what you want, one way is to clear it before the end.

```
vectora={ax,ay,az};
vectorb={bx,by,bz};
scalara=Norm[vectora];
directiona=vectora/scalara;
expr=Cross[vectorb,directiona]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
expr/. 1/scalara :> {Clear[scalara]; 1/scalara}
```

Gives what you want

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this clear the variable `scalara` so you have to reassign it again from the start.  But if you do not want to lose the definition of `scalara` each time, just replace the above with

```
expr/. 1/scalara -> {tmp=scalara;Clear[scalara]; 1/scalara} 
scalara=tmp;
```

This restores `scalara` to its old value right away.

Answer (score 1):

There could be better answers but here is what I found. Basically we look at the FullForm of the expression and do the replacement.

```
vectora = {ax, ay, az}
vectorb = {bx, by, bz}
scalara = Norm[vectora]
directiona = vectora/scalara
crs = Cross[vectorb, directiona]
```

This comes from the FullForm of the expression of scalara

```
replace = Power[Abs[ax]^2 + Abs[ay]^2 + Abs[az]^2, Rational[-1, 2]]

crs /. replace -> 1/sca

(*  {(az by)/sca - (ay bz)/sca, -((az bx)/sca) + (ax bz)/sca, (ay bx)/
  sca - (ax by)/sca}  *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr /. Power[_, Rational[-1, _] ]:> 1 / Defer[scalara]
FullSimplify[expr scalara] / Defer[scalara]
```

both give

> {(az by - ay bz)/scalara, (-az bx + ax bz)/scalara, (ay bx - ax by)/scalara}

Both work if `Defer` is replaced with `HoldForm`.